# Using the Tidyverse to the count the frequency of a specific string in REDCap data across multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, startswith, data-wrangling, redcap

I frequently receive data from REDCap surveys in which respondents are permitted to "Check" >1 response to a survey question. Each potential response is housed in its own column. I'd like to summarize the frequency with which each response option (column) has been checked.  For example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)
responses<-c("Checked", "Unchecked")
numobs<-10

my_example<-data.frame(id=1:10, 
                       Response_Option_A=sample(responses, numobs, replace=TRUE), 
                       Response_Option_B=sample(responses, numobs, replace=TRUE), 
                       Response_Option_C=sample(responses, numobs, replace=TRUE),
                       Response_Option_D=sample(responses, numobs, replace=TRUE),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_example
#>    id Response_Option_A Response_Option_B Response_Option_C Response_Option_D
#> 1   1         Unchecked         Unchecked         Unchecked           Checked
#> 2   2         Unchecked         Unchecked         Unchecked         Unchecked
#> 3   3         Unchecked         Unchecked         Unchecked           Checked
#> 4   4         Unchecked           Checked         Unchecked           Checked
#> 5   5           Checked         Unchecked         Unchecked           Checked
#> 6   6         Unchecked         Unchecked         Unchecked         Unchecked
#> 7   7           Checked         Unchecked           Checked           Checked
#> 8   8           Checked           Checked         Unchecked         Unchecked
#> 9   9           Checked         Unchecked         Unchecked         Unchecked
#> 10 10         Unchecked         Unchecked         Unchecked           Checked
```

My initial inclination was to try this, but it returns the total number of responses checked, rather than the number in each column.

```r
my_example %>%
  select(starts_with("Response_Option_")) %>%
    summarise(checked=sum(.=="Checked"))
#>   checked
#> 1      13
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Help summarizing these responses efficiently is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `tidyverse` approach to show the response totals per column, not by row. I assume, by how you worded your question, that this is what you are looking for. Also included is the `starts_with()` function which was included in your question tags.

We can use `pivot_longer()` to pivot the response features from wide to long then use `group_by` to define the variables taking the existing table and converting it to a grouped table where the `summarise(`) operation is used to create a new data frame with rows provided for each combination of grouping variables.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)
responses<-c("Checked", "Unchecked")
numobs<-10

my_example<-data.frame(id=1:10, 
                       Response_Option_A=sample(responses, numobs, replace=TRUE), 
                       Response_Option_B=sample(responses, numobs, replace=TRUE), 
                       Response_Option_C=sample(responses, numobs, replace=TRUE),
                       Response_Option_D=sample(responses, numobs, replace=TRUE),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_example %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Response_"), names_to = "Responses", 
               values_to = "value") %>% 
  group_by(Responses, value) %>%
  summarise(total_responses = n())


#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   Responses [4]
#>   Responses         value     total_responses
#>   <chr>             <chr>               <int>
#> 1 Response_Option_A Checked                 4
#> 2 Response_Option_A Unchecked               6
#> 3 Response_Option_B Checked                 2
#> 4 Response_Option_B Unchecked               8
#> 5 Response_Option_C Checked                 1
#> 6 Response_Option_C Unchecked               9
#> 7 Response_Option_D Checked                 6
#> 8 Response_Option_D Unchecked               4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you want just the `Checked` responses, you can add the following line of code after the `summarise()` operation:

```
filter(value == "Checked")

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   Responses [4]
#>   Responses         value   total_responses
#>   <chr>             <chr>             <int>
#> 1 Response_Option_A Checked               4
#> 2 Response_Option_B Checked               2
#> 3 Response_Option_C Checked               1
#> 4 Response_Option_D Checked               6
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the `tidyREDCap` package.  It has a bunch of functions to help process *check all that apply* variables coming from REDCap.  The package is on CRAN and the website which is on [github.io](https://raymondbalise.github.io/tidyREDCap/index.html) has the vignettes off the articles drop down at the top of the page.

Comment: Can you give an example in this answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `summarise` with `across` :

```
library(dplyr)
my_example %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("Response_Option_"), ~sum(. == 'Checked')))

#  Response_Option_A Response_Option_B Response_Option_C Response_Option_D
#1                 4                 2                 1                 6
```

In older version of `dplyr` you could use `summarise_at` :

```
my_example %>%
     summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Response_Option_")), ~sum(. == 'Checked'))
```

Comment: I needed to count the number of "Checked" values in each column, not each row.

Answer (score 0):

A very `base R` solution would be:

```
my_example$checked <- apply(my_example[,which(grepl('Response_Option_',names(my_example)))],1,
                            function(x) length(which(x=="Checked")))
```

Output:

```
   id Response_Option_A Response_Option_B Response_Option_C Response_Option_D checked
1   1         Unchecked         Unchecked         Unchecked           Checked       1
2   2         Unchecked         Unchecked         Unchecked         Unchecked       0
3   3         Unchecked         Unchecked         Unchecked           Checked       1
4   4         Unchecked           Checked         Unchecked           Checked       2
5   5           Checked         Unchecked         Unchecked           Checked       2
6   6         Unchecked         Unchecked         Unchecked         Unchecked       0
7   7           Checked         Unchecked           Checked           Checked       3
8   8           Checked           Checked         Unchecked         Unchecked       2
9   9           Checked         Unchecked         Unchecked         Unchecked       1
10 10         Unchecked         Unchecked         Unchecked           Checked       1
```

Also a very optimal way with credits for @r2evans:

```
my_example$checked <- rowSums(my_example[, grep("^Response_", colnames(my_example))] == "Checked")
```

Which produces same previous output and it more readable.

Comment: or just `rowSums(my_example[, grep("^Response_", colnames(my_example))] == "Checked")` (assigned to a column). There should be no need to use both `which` and `grepl`, grepl or grep by itself should suffice.

Comment: @r2evans It is a great suggestion, could I add to this answer to improve it?

Comment: absolutely, go ahead

Comment: @r2evans Great, I have added the optimal way you mentioned. Many thanks for allowing it.